# Is it possible to simulate orientation and size change for responsive design with an IFRAME (w/o reload of page)?

Tags: javascript, iframe

For the fast answering: I am not asking how to resize an `iframe` based on content and I am not asking how to simulate responsive design in browser when developing.

**EDIT**:

**I realized, that I was testing with a "half responsible" design, that needs a "resize" event on document / body, but this does not fire and I can't trigger 
  The full responsible seems to work**

I want my customers to get a chance / feeling how their content would look on a smartphone (ie. responsive)

I do not want to push them into a development mode and browser details. My customers are not developers and not designers.

Therefore I made them a "Phone - Preview" that's opening an iframe popup with some phone dimensions.

This  works fine.

The customer also can change the size / orientation, *but this only works fine if I am reloading (the in principle responsive) context of the iframe*

Is there a way to trigger / push the (same domain) IFRAME content / rendering to react to the changes of the IFRAME?

I tried to resize the body, but this does not change the situation.

So is it possible?

For those who want to see some source (it's coffee, sorry, but the logic is clear I think )

```
display_change: =>
    horz=@$rotate.rm_get() #this is my way to read date from any input 0 or 1 here
    mt=@$mobile_type.rm_get('all') # this reads all data with the selection here [1, 'best phone', 'best phone', 300, 600] rendered into the select
    [w,h]=[mt[3],mt[4]]
    [w,h]=[h,w] if horz

    #ok width and height are here now.

    $iframe=@$form.find('iframe')
    .height(h)
    .width(w)

    # how to avoid force reload?
    $iframe.prop(src: $iframe.prop("src"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the iframe's orientation from inside or outside of the iframe. From the inside, I believe you can set `window.orientation` manually. From the outside, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Here's a similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820096/how-to-change-the-iframes-orientation).

Comment: your answer engaged me to search further, it was a completely different problem. I wrote $(window).on('resize, load', @prepare_all) you see the comma?

Comment: and this one explains many probs I had, this fulittle (this word is meant) komma!

Comment: ok ok, for those - my friends - just asking me whats "fulittle" - in my company we use it for "fu**ing little" describing a small thing that makes real problems  like forgotten commas or dots  ....

Answer (score 0):

**Answer form OP**: For others stepping into this question: 
It works all fine, check other errors, IFRAME fires the resize event