# Is it possible to make iframe daily motion videos into Full screen orientation rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

> Is it possible to make iframe dailymotion videos into FullScreen?
>   Orientation rotation?

Answer (score 0):

The body has a default margin in most browsers. Try this to make into [fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

in the page with the iframe.

About the orientation's iframe you can changes that into landscape or portrait. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18820729/9379280) i have the reference about the orientation.

Then for the [rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727978/how-to-rotate-an-iframe-using-javascript), there is the transform property in css3

```
someid {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

hope it helps.